# .DLL failing to inject when calling curl_easy_init()

Tags: c++, dll, libcurl

I'm trying to inject a C++ .dll into a process, so then I can retrieve information from an Apache server to use it inside the process.
The problem is that when I call curl_easy_init(), the .dll fails to inject.
This is my code:

```
#include "includes.h"
extern HollowAim* hollow;

static size_t WriteCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

void offsets::curlServer() {
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    char* readBuffer = NULL;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://carinae-studios.cf/csgo/cpp/offsets.php");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        hollow->settings.showOffWarn = true;
        hollow->settings.showOffWarnText = curl_easy_strerror(res);
    }
    else
    {
        hollow->settings.showOffWarn = false;
        offsets::setOffsets(readBuffer);
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

void offsets::setOffsets(char* res) {
    hollow->settings.showOffWarn = true;
    hollow->settings.showOffWarnText = res;
}
```

I have no idea what could be causing this. I'm pretty sure it's curl_easy_init(), because if I comment everything from curl = curl_easy... to the end of the curlServer function, the .dll injects successfully. There's no debug messages from the injector.